# specifiying directory of Python module when calling it from C++

Tags: c++, python

When trying to to import and execute a function within a Python module from a C++ executable, how can I pass in the directory where the module is located as a command line argument?

Answer (score 2):

Python honors `PYTHONPATH` environmental variable. It is a `PATH` like environmental variable specifying paths where Python loads modules.

Inside `.py` script `PYTHONPATH` can be accessed and updated through the `sys.path` variable.

If you can show more source code how you create Python interpreter more helpful answer can be given.